# GitHub workflow start one after another

Tags: javascript, github, continuous-integration, workflow, continuous-deployment

I am trying to make GitHub workflows run so that 1st.yml only starts after the 2nd.yml is done.

1st.yml

```
on:
   workflow_dispatch:


jobs:
   // whatever
```

2nd.yml

```
No idea here how to throw dispatch event.
```

I am not sure how to throw some kind of event from 2nd.yml to 1st.yml so that 1st.yml knows that 2nd.yml is finished.

`workflow_dispatch` doesn't make sense, because what if I have 3 workflows and I only want to start 2nd.yml when 1st.yml is done and 3rd.yml starts as soon as possible.